# laravel - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel

*Asking for your help again please. Im getting the above error on registration module. This is working before. I tried to make a my profile edit page and then this happens. Hoping for your help please.. Thank you in advance *

**User Controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Model\user\user;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('user.user.show',compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
            ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => request('name'),
            'email' => request('email'),
            ]);
        $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));
        auth()->login($user);

        return redirect(route('index'));;
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('user.user.edit', compact('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'email' => ['required','email',Rule::unique('users')->ignore($id)],
            'password' => ['required','password',Rule::unique('users')->ignore($id)]
             ]);

        //$user = Auth::user();       
        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->firstname = $request->firstname;
        $user->middlename = $request->middlename;
        $user->lastname = $request->lastname;
        $user->nationality = $request->nationality;
        $user->gender = $request->gender;
        $user->civilstatus = $request->name;
        $user->mobilenum = $request->mobilenum;
        $user->worknum = $request->worknun;
        $user->workadd = $request->workadd;
        $user->homeadd = $request->homeadd;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->birthday = $request->birthday;

        $user->save();

        return redirect(route('user.user.show'))->with('message','Announcement Updated Succesfully');;

    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
```

**Blade file:**

```
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf
                    <div class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary text-left" style="width: 100%;" type="button"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>&nbsp; Continue with Facebook</button></div>
                    <div class="text-center mt-2"><button class="btn btn-light text-left border-dark" style="width: 100%;" type="button"><i class="fa fa-google"></i>&nbsp; Continue with Google</button></div>
                    <form class="mt-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="text-primary input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i></span></div><input class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus placeholder="Full Name">
                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                                <div class="input-group-append"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="text-primary input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></span></div><input class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" placeholder="Email">
                                @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                                <div class="input-group-append"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="text-primary input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></div><input class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
                                @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                                <div class="input-group-append"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="text-primary input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></div><input class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
                                <div class="input-group-append"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**Model/users/user.php**

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname', 'birthday', 'nationality', 
        'gender', 'civilstatus', 'mobilenum', 'worknum', 'workadd',
        'homeadd', 
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. Make your table definition so the password can be nullable
2. Use the `new User([...])` syntax over `User::create([...])`. The first one does not insert directly, the latter will.

Table definition example:

```php
Schema::create('users', function ($table) {
    // other user table fields ...
    $table->string('password')->nullable();
});
```

Example without ::create (as given by @Rwd):

```php
// NOT User::create([...]) but new User([...]);
$user = new User([
  'name'  => request('name'),
  'email' => request('email'),
]);
$user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));
$user->save(); // dont forget to save when not using ::create([...]) syntax
```

Comment: Since you're not persisting the `User` until after you've added the password to the instance, why does the password field have to be `nullable`?

Comment: I believe @Eelke posted both valid but independent solutions. First, make a password nullable, so a user without a password can be inserted. Second, creating a User instance (not persisted), setting the password, and then persisting: so persisted user directly have a password. I would clearly recommend the second one: that keep the password field required in DB.

Comment: I would also recommend the second one, but the OP did not seem to notice the valid solution given by @Rwd did not use the `::create` syntax. Or at least, did not recognise this as an immediate insert versus instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this issue is because `password` isn't **mass assignable** i.e. it isn't in your `$fillable` array.

Methods like `create()` or `fill()` are protected from [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment). To get around this you can either add `password` to your `$fillable` array or set it explicitly e.g.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'name'     => 'required',
        'email'    => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed',
    ]);

    $user = new User([
        'name'  => request('name'),
        'email' => request('email'),
    ]);
    $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));
    $user->save();

    auth()->login($user);

    return redirect(route('index'));;
}
```

Comment: Hello Rwd, thanks for your help, but problem still exists. I updated create() function as instructed. Did I get you correctly?

Comment: @imurangel Please can you edit your question to show the updated code.

Comment: @imurangel No, that won't work. You're changing the password but you're not saving it after. The code I provided was intended to replace the code you have i.e. so you could copy and paste it. I'll update my answer to show the entire store method.

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you again, but still with the same error. -> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (myuser, eadd@gmail.com, 2020-05-17 10:02:22, 2020-05-17 10:02:22))

Comment: @imurangel Have you copied the code in my answer exactly?